# Pod is restarted faster each time

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a pod that runs a java spring boot service that is disk intensive and eventually gets OOMkilled due to kernel's memory (assume that is inode and page cash) increasing until hits the limit (3Gb). This takes approximately 2 days. This is a separate issue that we are investigating
But the problem is that after this first restart, it gets OOMKilled each time faster and faster until it falls into Crashloop. It first lasts 1 hour, then less and less. `kubectl top pods` shows that memory went back to normal but still suddenly the container gets killed.

So my questions are:

1. K8s sends a kill to the main process of the container so pod per se is not replaced, right?. What happens with pod resources? Are they cleaned up between container restarts?
2. What happens with the pod when its container is restarted? Could this be a java leak of some type, file handles? Java memory is pretty low (under 800Mb). JVM is killed in the restart process so that should be happening.
3. Is it possible that the Node hosting the pod does not free or clear what pod was using?

Deleting the pod with `kubectl delete pod` does the job and it last 2 days again. Probably because the node frees the pod and re-allocates it.

We basically log the pod's memory values taking data from `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory` folder and after the first restart, values go back to normal but it is still being killed.

We are using:

- CentOS with kernel 3.10 in the nodes
- Java 1.8 (`1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12`)
- I have configured JVM with cgroup awareness options but we know that java is not OOMing.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example application to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Not so easy. My application is a service (spring boot) that uses JGit and handles git requests on a shared FS (so it is very intense disk usage). Opening files makes kernel 's cache memory grow  . We tried the same without java,  just a pod with a `dd` command. Same effect. That is our first problem. After restart app goes up again normally, and after a while (30 min or so) it gets killed again, according to `describe pod` is OOMKilled but we are monitoring memory and everything is normal there. So I thought that something between Docker, CentOS and K8s is holding something.

Comment: have you solved this issue ?